# How to find out the XAML file that produces a XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I get the following error at runtime from a C# WPF application:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Set property
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '6' and line position '6'.

How can I find which file this is associated with?  The Visual Studio solution contains two XAML files, `app.xaml` and `MainWindow.xaml`.

I am using VS 2010 on Windows 7.  The application targets .NET 4.0.

UPDATE:

Following up on Kasper's helpful suggestion, I displayed the exception in detail, and this is what it showed:

[image]

Based on the information in there, I was able to gather that a certain DLL was missing.  Supplying the DLL fixed this problem, but I still have other XAML parse errors coming up.

Comment: As the stack trace reads, you need to add reference to Microsoft.Windows.Shell assembly.

Comment: @E-Bat That's the DLL I was talking about when I said "... a certain DLL was missing."

Comment: Make sure it is copied to the correct output folder. Also in the its reference check that Copy Local property is set to true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code-behind, the XAML code is parsed in the method InitializeComponent which is automatically generated. This method is called in the Window object's constructor. So to have more details about the exception, put the call to InitializeComponent in a try/catch block. This way, you have access to the useless XamlParseException, but also to its InnerExceptions and to the StackTrace.

UPDATE!
You can call the inner exception using a MessageDialog.

```
public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
{
public Window1()
{
  try

  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
  // Log error (including InnerExceptions!)
  // Handle exception
   MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.InnerException);
   dialog.ShowAsync();

  }
 }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

There is also another trick to this:

- Open the "Exceptions" window (Debug/Exceptions) in Visual Studio.
- Click "add"
- Add "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException"
- Check the box to break on throw for this exception.
- Hit F5!

You'll find that the XamlParseException you catch is much more descriptive, and will give the correct position in the xaml file.

Let me know if this was easier :)

Comment: Before I go off and try this, a +1 for "the useless XamlParseException"! :)

Comment: Please see my update above.  How do I display inner exceptions?

Comment: I updated my answer with a easier way, and how you can call the inner exception :) Let me know if it works out.

Comment: Thanks Kasper.  The format of the messages are a mess, but the information contained within allowed me to figure out the missing DLLs.  By the way, `MessageDialog` does not exist on Windows 7. FYI! :)

Comment: I mean, no XamlParseException ever references a filename.  Only Line number and position - just useless.

Comment: `MessageDialog` is a UWP class. `System.Windows.MessageBox` is the WPF class.